# Get values from JSON in node.js

Tags: json

I am trying to get only the values inside a JSON, but the return is coming between quotes []

```
var data = dataResult.retorno;
var myString = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(myString);
    // Return
    //  [{"messsage":"Content of message one"},{"messsage":"Content of message two"}]
for(let i of data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(i).map(key => i[key])));
}
    // Return
    // [Content of message one]
    // [Content of message two]
```

How do I receive the values without quotes ??

Comment: By "quotes" you seem to mean square brackets. It's an *array*, why wouldn't they be there?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I expected the value to come back without the brackets

Comment: jonrsharpe, I am not able to extract the value inside the brackets.